# Why couldn't Ransom make an anonymous call?

Tags: plot-explanation, knives-out

In *Knives Out* (2019), Detective Benoit reveals Ransom's plan:

> **Benoit:** Marta will get arrested for killing Fran and Harlan. And it would have worked if we hadn't have brought you in for questioning so you could not make your anonymous call. And if Fran had not stashed a safety copy of the tox report.

Why couldn't he make an anonymous call if the police haven't brought him in for questioning?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, detective Benoit is saying that if the police hadn't brought in Ransom for questioning, he could have made that anonymous call he originally planned for.

Ransom originally planned to make that call after he and Marta visited that burned laboratory. But the detective saw him and started chasing them. The plan could've still worked when Marta and Ransom stopped, but that's when the police arrived and they took Ransom in for questioning.

Answer (score 3):

The point of the call was in the timing. Ransom's plan was to meet Fran at the laundromat at 8AM, which is what Fran originally organised.

[image: Fran's original blackmail letter]

Kill Fran. He used morphine to mirror Marta's accident with Harlan to make Marta more suspicious.

[image: Ransom getting morphine out of a bottle, with Fran's body in the background, blurred]

Then get Marta to arrive at Fran's location at 10AM. During which he had planned to anonymously call the police so that they would arrive and find Marta at Fran's dead body.

[image]

However, because Ransom was arrested, he wasn't able to make that anonymous call *at the right time*. He could still have made the call afterwards, but presumably, they would have just found Fran's dead body with no Marta.

Not that it mattered, because Marta

> ends up calling an ambulance and performs CPR to try and save Fran.